# conditional formatting: I want to use javascript for rounded corner but only if it's in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I use -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius for making rounded corner. However as we know IE 7 doesn't support that. What I would like to do is to basically use standard for firefox and Safari however for IE I would like to use javascript.  by using this http://www.editsite.net/blog/rounded_corners.html

My question is how can i make conditional so that each browser know the way to render the page?

Comment: FYI, `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` are anything but standard. CSS properties beginning with `-` are browser-specific. `border-radius` was introduced in CSS3, but CSS3 support isn't really widespread yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius rules in your CSS, IE will completely ignore them. You can place the javascript for IE using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rounded('rounded', 6, 6);
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

All browsers other than IE will completely ignore this. If you want this only for a specific version of IE, use this instead:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rounded('rounded', 6, 6);
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include a `<script>` for MSIE only.